# Merge [android-architecture-components] into [android-arch]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[android-architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-components) should be a synonym  for [android-arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-arch).

Merging this direction allows handy sub-tags for the already existing tags for individual components like [android-arch-lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-arch-lifecycle).

Actually, I'd prefer if everything were just a little more verbose - *android-architecture* and *android-architecture-lifecycle* would be my preference, but these tags don't already exist.

Answer (score 5):

The following have been syn'd and merged

- [android-arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-arch) -> [android-architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-components)
- [android-arch-lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-arch-lifecycle) -> [android-architecture-lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-lifecycle)

Note that I've not preserved any tag wikis/excerpts as they were nothing more than "Use this tag for questions about [tag name]" - so if someone wants to address that by suggesting/making an edit please feel free.

Comment: There is also [tag:architecture-components], which basically is the same thing (64 of 64 are tagged with [tag:android]). Please create this synonym too!

Comment: Now there is a request for that -- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359090/merge-architecture-components-into-android-architecture-components