# Merge [architecture-components] into [android-architecture-components]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Right now these tags are about the same [collection of Android libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html).

Current stats:

- [architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture-components) - 84 questions, 100% tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [android-architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-components) - 297 questions, 100% tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

The tag [architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture-components) is generic and doesn't follow the convention of prefixing `android-` in tags that address Android-specific components (e.g., [android-fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragment), [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity)). While it hasn't attracted any generic software architecture questions right now, it's possible that this could happen in the future and the tag would become ambiguous.

<sub>Note: follows on from [this question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358088/merge-android-architecture-components-into-android-arch) which addresses a slightly different merge.</sub>

Comment: I think it makes sense to use it as a synonym.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @VadimKotov but I think [tag:architecture-components] is too ambiguous to be a tag and should be merged and deleted. I'm happy to do the work myself I just wanted to follow the community guidelines by seeking approval first

Comment: You're absolutely right, because mods can do it without retagging each question. Feel free to remove [synonym-request] from your question. But I still think it makes sense

Comment: @VadimKotov thanks I'll leave your edit in for now in case someone else has the same opinion